# boost mpi example compile

Tags: boost, compilation, mpi

I'm going to use boost_mpi, but the following problems occurred while I was compiling the test program.

#### Problem

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_info_null'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_request_null'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_packed'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_comm_null'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_errors_return'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Comm::Comm()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_op_set_cxx_callback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_datatype_null'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_comm_world'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_unsigned_long'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_group_empty'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

## Other information

My libboost was installed by apt-get install libboost-dev-all, and version number is 1.54.
My GCC version is 4.8.4, MPICH version is 3.2.

Here is my testing code:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::mpi::environment env{argc, argv};
    boost::mpi::communicator world;
    std::cout << world.rank() << ", " << world.size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `libboost_mpi.so` is built on top of Open MPI (e.g. **not** MPICH). You should either install and use boostmpi built on top of MPICH, or install and use Open MPI

Comment: How can i install boostmpi built on top of MPICH? I just use apt-get install boost-all.

Comment: per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505476/using-mpich-with-boost-mpi-on-ubuntu there is no such package and you should either rebuild boostmpi, or use Open MPI

Answer (score 0):

What Ubuntu version are you using? The above looks a little odd. Looks like a really old system?

```
apt -y install libboost-mpi-dev libmpich-dev openmpi-bin
```

should set you up just fine. `libboost-mpi-dev` is not part of `boost-all`. Afterwards build your code:

```
mpicxx -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp -lboost_mpi
```

where you code is in `test.cpp`. Test with:

```
mpiexec -np 4 ./test
```

Comment: Ubuntu version is 14.04. The reason is my libboost_mpi.so is built on top of openmp not mpich.

Comment: i understand. But how did you install everything? Using `apt`?

Comment: why? just run the command above. updated my answer. works flawlessly on 14.04.

Comment: There's no way to avoid installing openmpi due to the package dependencies.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505476/using-mpich-with-boost-mpi-on-ubuntu

Comment: look above. all works. just run the commands. really line by line. i just tested on 14.04. over openvpn and iphone + ssh. LOL

Comment: which MPI library is used when "it works" ? mpich ? Open MPI ?

Comment: OpenMPI at runtime.

Comment: @JZH would really appreciate it, if you accepted the answer above! I took a little time out to help.

Comment: uh..In fact, I need MPICH not OpenMP, so the only way I can do is rebuild boostmpi?

Comment: let me see. accept the answer above and i keep trying to help.

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem has been solved by using @GillesGouaillardet method.

Comment: nice waste of time.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour if you had read the comments of the question, you would have noticed your answer did not fit the OP needs, and hence there was no need to ask or rant about your answer being accepted.